# Sporadic behaviour with Session variables in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've been scratching my head as to why this code will work some of the time, but not all (or at least most of the time). I've found that it actually does run displaying the correct content in the browser some of the time, but strangely there will be days when I'll come back to the same code, run the server (as per normal) and upon loading the page will receive an error in the console: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Session.get('x').html')`

(When I receive that error there will be times where the next line in the console will read `Error` - referring to the `err` object, and other times when it will read `Object` - referring the `data` object!?).

I'm obviously missing something about Session variables in Meteor and must be misusing them? I'm hoping someone with experience can point me in the right direction.

Thanks, in advance for any help!

Here's my dummy code:

```
/client/del.html
<head>
  <title>del</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  Hello World!
  <div class="helloButton">{{{greeting}}}</div>
</template>
```

My client-side javascript file is:

```
/client/del.js
Meteor.call('foo', 300, function(err, data) {
  err ? console.log(err) : console.log(data);
  Session.set('x', data);
});

Template.hello.events = {
  'click div.helloButton' : function(evt) {
    if ( Session.get('x').answer.toString() === evt.target.innerHTML ) {
      console.log('yay!');
    }
  } 
};

Template.hello.greeting = function() {
  return Session.get('x').html;
};
```

And my server-side javascript is:

```
/server/svr.js
Meteor.methods({

  doubled: function(num) {
    return num * 2;
  },

  foo: function(lmt) {
    var count = lmt,
        result = {};

    for ( var i = 0; i < lmt; i++ ) {
        count++;
    }

    count = Meteor.call('doubled', count);

    result.html = "<em>" + count + "</em>";
    result.answer = count;
    return result;

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that the session variable won't be set yet when the client first starts up. So `Session.get('x')` will return `undefined` until your method call (`foo`) returns, which almost certainly won't happen before the template first draws.

However after that it will be in the session, so things will probably behave right once you refresh.

The answer is to just check if it's `undefined` before trying to access the variable. For example:

```
Template.hello.greeting = function() {
  if (Session.get('x')) return Session.get('x').html;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for your reply. I was under the impression that once the session variables are set that it would automatically update the Session.get references. I tried your solution above and I get the same error above with the `data` Object returned in the console.log a second later.

Comment: @rs77: yeah it does automatically update. So what will happen is the code in `Template.hello.greeting` will be evaluated for each value the session variable takes. You just need to be careful that it never runs into an error; your code is basically right, you just have to get past the initial `undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I think I had entered your code incorrectly: `if (Session.get('x').html)) return Session.get('x').html` but upon reading Tom Wijsman's response below saw the error of my way and the code worked as you had stated. I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one and would like to thank Tom Wijsman for his additional insights (I wish I could tick both of you correct!!). Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is bad sollution due to fact it will leave it empty (but unused).

It should use Session.setDefatult('x', ''); instead.

Answer (score 1):

One of the [seven principles](http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples) of Meteor is:

> *Latency Compensation*. On the client, use prefetching and model simulation to make it look like you have a zero-latency connection to the database.

Because there is latency, your client will first attempt to draw the lay-out according to the data it has at the moment your client connects. Then it will do the call and then it will update according to the call. Sometimes the call might be able to respond fast enough to be drawn at the same time.

As now there is a chance for the variable to not be set, it would throw an exception in that occasion and thus break down execution (as the functions in the call stack will not continue to run).

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Check that the variable is set when using it.

   `return Session.get('x') ? Session.get('x').html : '';`
2. Make sure the variable has an initial value by setting it at the top of the script.

   `Session.set('x', { html = '', answer = ''});`

Another approach would be to add the templates once the call responds.

```
Meteor.call('foo', 300, function(err, data) {
    Session.set('x', data);
    $('#page').html(Meteor.ui.render(function() {
        return Template.someName();
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks once again Tom for your help! I found the error when I saw your response and tried your step 1 (as Tom Coleman had suggested). My apologies for being a klutz! Thanks once again.